# Converting points from one canvas to another with CreatePageVisual, and TransformToVisual

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have this bit of code that uses DocumentToolkit to Print a XPS document:

protected override UIElement CreatePageVisual(FixedPage fixedPage, Size maxSize)
        {
            Canvas page = (Canvas)base.CreatePageVisual(fixedPage, maxSize);

```
        foreach (Tuple<int, UIElement, int, int> t in AllFields.Where(f => f.Item1 == fixedPage.PageNumber))
        {
            var clone = t.Item2.Clone();

            Canvas.SetLeft(clone, t.Item3 * 1.335);
            Canvas.SetTop(clone, (790 - t.Item4) * 1.335);
            page.Children.Add(clone);
        }
     }
```

t.Item2 and t.Item3 are the X,Y coordinates of UIElements on a Canvas.  It displays perfectly with these coordinates, but if I go to print the document using the override above my UIElements are "stretched" over the canvas.  In the top left they are very close to being correct, but if I go down the page or across the page they are incorrect.

I tried to convert the coordinates using TransformVisual but no luck:

```
        GeneralTransform generalTransform = t.Item2.TransformToVisual(page);
        Point childToParentCoordinates = generalTransform.Transform(new Point(t.Item3 * 1.335, (790 - t.Item4) * 1.335));
        Canvas.SetLeft(clone, childToParentCoordinates.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(clone, childToParentCoordinates.Y);
```

I get an error, and I'm not sure if it will work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had a couple of things wrong.  First my TransformToVisual(page) should have been TransformToVisual(page.Parent).  And ultimately the real issue that I was having is that I should've been adding my clone's to fixedPage instead of page.

Essentially I was adding my textblocks to a canvas inside of a canvas.  I tried to TransformToVisual to fix it, but I ended up deleting all of that and adding my items to fixedPage instead.